# Django ModelForm not saving data to Model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, modelform

I created a model and respective ModelForm, view and Template for it, but ModelForm does not save data to the model even though .save() function is used. 
I have tried reviewing forms and views but I do not know what is wrong.I have posted the respective models, forms, views and templates in the question.

models.py:

```
class Centre(models.Model):
    Location = (
    ('rashmi_heights', 'Rashmi Heights Centre'),
    ('Levana', 'Levana Centre')
)

    name= models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, choices=Location, unique=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length =250)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    phone = PhoneField(blank=True, help_text='Contact phone number')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py:

```
class CentreForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Centre
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py:

```
def centre(request):

    forms = CentreForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        forms = CentreForm(request.POST)

        if forms.is_valid():

            centre = forms.save(request.POST)
            centre.save()

        else:
            forms = CentreForm()

    return render(request,'NewApp/centreinfo.html',{'forms':forms})
```

template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% extends 'NewApp/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block body_block %}

<div class="jumbotron">

    <h2>Fill details about your centre.</h2><br>
    <h3> </h3>

    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{forms.as_p}}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'NewApp:centreinfo' %}">Submit</a>
    </form>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
forms.py:

class CentreForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: -> change here
        model = Centre
        fields = '__all__'


def centre(request):
    forms = CentreForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        forms = CentreForm(request.POST)
        if forms.is_valid():
            forms.save(request.POST)
        else:
            forms = CentreForm()

    return render(request,'NewApp/centreinfo.html',{'forms':forms})
```

html

```
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{forms.as_p}}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: That worked. But I don't really understand what was the problem. Because other views and forms seem to work fine with the same syntax.

Comment: the problem was with Meta and not Meta(), and you had duplicated entry for saving in the view

Comment: Thank you so much.